# Eslint 8.0.1 - implementing jest into config throws an error

Tags: javascript, typescript, config, eslint

In my Next/React/Typescript/Jest project I'm trying to configure my eslint config.
After updating to version 8.x (currently 8.0.1), the linter throws following error:

```
Error: .eslintrc.js » ./eslint/config.js:
    Environment key "jest/globals" is unknown
```

Then I added `'plugin:jest/recommended'` to the `extends` array in my `config.js`, which led me to this error:

```
TypeError: Failed to load plugin 'jest' declared in '.eslintrc.js » ./eslint/config.js': Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

The plugin is installed and inside my `package.json`. Even several `npm ci` haven't helped me here.

Would appreciate ideas !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using any other eslint plugins? If so, has npm warned you of any peer dependency issues?

I ran into this same issue when upgrading to eslint v8.0.1. In may case, one plugin I listed an an earlier version of `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` as a direct dependency (`@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` is also a peer dependency of `eslint-plugin-jest`). This earlier version of `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` was not compatible with `eslint` v8.0.1. So I opted to downgrade to v7.32.0

If you have control over the other plugins you use, you might upgrade their dependencies and publish a new release. Else, you'll probably have to downgrade `eslint` in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Luckily I was in control of all peer dependencies. In my case though, eslint needed the latest version of `eslint-plugin-jest` (25.2.2) and `eslint-plugin-testing-library` v5 which has been released a few days ago.

Comment: I resolved this with `yarn up -R @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser` to upgrade sub-dependencies, `yarn add --dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser` to explicitly define these dependencies, and adding `parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'` and `plugin: '@typescript-eslint/parser'` to the eslintrc file to explicitly reference them.